# CSS jQuery hoverZoom Hover effect, different results on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I've created a plant database, the client wanted a small image of each plant, that grows in size when you hover over it. I found a jQuery that seemed to work from here: https://github.com/jmar/jquery-hoverZoom

The first time a page loads and you hover over the image, the image isn't centered in the grey box (it's shifted down). Any time after the first time you hover over the image, it is centered in the box. I can't figure out why this is only happening the first time you load the page. I have a "test" page which works fine. The thumbnail image of the plant also shifts position on the page after the first time you hover over it.

I don't know much about the jQuery, so if that's causing the problem I'm not sure how to fix it. I suspect there's some conflicting CSS, but can't find it.

NOT WORKING: http://briggs.honeycombsites.com/plants/product-search/ (NOTE: Click on any of the plants here to take you to the plant page where the hover is set up)

TEST PAGE: http://briggs.honeycombsites.com/test/ (works fine the first time)

ALSO - This doesn't seem to work in Chrome, or Safari :( Once you hover over the image the first time, the thumbnail disappears entirely.

Comment: Probably because after the first load, the images are cached. In the first load, the images are probably still loading when the plugin code attempts to retrieve the image dimensions and thus fail. Just a random shot.

Comment: Are you sticking to jQuery for cross-browser compatibility? If not, what about using CSS3 transforms?

Comment: I'd be willing to use CSS3 for sure, however I couldn't figure out how to use CSS3, and have the image scale correctly. ie. The image is ___ in size, if viewing it on a large browser I want it to fill the screen, if viewing in a small browser I want it to fill the screen. When I was using CSS the image kept getting cut off in small browsers.

Comment: @Fabrício It works fine on the test page the first time though. So I'm not sure why it doesn't work on the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the scale to the elements on roll over following the basic syntax of this:

CSS

```
.yourClass {   
   transform: scale(1, 1);   
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.yourClass:hover {   
   transform: scale(3, 3);   
}
```

If you have the element within a div I believe you will have to apply it similarly to the parent div. Also, for cross browser functionality, be sure to use the vendor prefixes on both the transition and the transform:

```
 -webkit-
 -moz-
 -o-
 -ms-
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong, but this doesn't seem to solve my requirement of the image expanding past the borders of the page if it's a small screen size. I've added your suggestion to my test page, the image basically just grows 3 times in size, which is what I had before I switched to jQuery: http://briggs.honeycombsites.com/test/

Comment: make a fiddle please... if your site changes this question is no longer helpful to future users.

Comment: AGAIN... vendor prefixing. Updated fiddle works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/T9BvX/2/

Comment: AGAIN... This does not do what I want it to. It just get's bigger and zoom outside the browser window. I need the image to ONLY scale to the dimentions of the browser window. if the window is 1024x768, the image should be no bigger than 768 in height. I don't think you can do this with just CSS, which is why I'm trying the jQuery. 
On my test page, the first image does want I want, minus the issues I layed out earlier, and your image just get's bigger, which is not what I'm looking for: http://briggs.honeycombsites.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a conflict between your main style.css `ul` and `li` styles and the zoom's style. Try placing `jquery.hoverZoom.css` last, before `</head>` and see if the placement of the thumb is correct afterwards.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I will look into possibly changing the ul, li styles. At least it's a starting point for problem solving.